# Google Home API for going to a URL and login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am a very new developer who can write basic HTML (yes I know it's English), and is looking for a solution to a problem that I basically invented.

I recently bought a product called Doorbird, a very cool and well engineered IP Doorbell. The reason I bought it, is because it has an App, and integrates with IP phones and support video, and has a few bells and whistles, if you're not familiar with this product, I highly recommend looking at it.

The "problem" is that it does not integrate with Google Home, or Amazon Echo. However, it does have an API that allows you to go to the URL, login and unlock the door. I was looking into creating my own action that would have the Google Home login to the Doorbell and go to the unlock URL.

My issue is, I have no experience with this, but I pick things up very quickly, and believe in myself!

I already looked at the api.ai site from Google, and have signed up. It looked simple, but upon further investigation looks very complicated.

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks in advance,

-Jack G

Comment: Just took a quick look at their api and it looks very simple. U can authenticate using request parameters. In order to send that url from a google action u would have to build a dialog flow fullfillment service. You can do this for free using .net core and heroku. Good luck

Comment: Just saw this on the Google Daigflow portal, looks very simple. Thanks so much. I’ll update here when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need them to publish their REST api so that you can call the 'action' to unlock directly vs. having to go to a login page.  You would probably set up oauth to have your server talk to theirs or use web headers.  Ask their tech support if they support direct REST api using a security model.